# How to embed an image on Github

Tags: github

I use gh-pages to host a website, and I am familiar with markdown. My question, though, makes reference to inserting an image (perhaps saved within *Issues*) so that it is visible on a regular repository code file. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that file is `.md` or `.rst`(not sure if it works for other), you can do that either by saving image to your repo, or to the issues and then if image is in repo you can access it either with absolute or relative path:

- `![](raw path to your image - click on raw and copy&paste)`
- `![](folder/image.png)` folder is in root

If you mind sizing, use html, though I'm not sure if it works with relative paths too.

- `<img src="<url>" width=500></img>`

It's not possible to embed an image so it'd be visible in your *raw* code as I see on your image. To accomplish it only in a similar way, put your code in backticks and leave the rest in markdown or html.